# Difficulties filtering manage_nav-menus_columns

Tags: menus

I realize I've asked similar in the past, but I've currently running in some difficulties editing/removing the admin nav menu advanced menu properties. (without using jQuery)

```
add_filter( 'manage_nav-menus_columns', 'cor_wp_nav_menu_manage_columns');
function cor_wp_nav_menu_manage_columns() {
  return array(
    '_title' => 'test',
    'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
    'link-target' => __('Link Target'),
    'css-classes' => __('CSS Classes'),
    'xfn' => __('Link Relationship (XFN)'),
    'description' => __('Description'),
  );
}
```

In this case I was trying to rename the title key to something like 'test' to see if my filter would work.
The outcome however stayed the same '*title' => _*('Show advanced menu properties'),.

If possible, this is what I'm actually trying to accomplish:

```
add_filter( 'manage_nav-menus_columns', 'cor_wp_nav_menu_manage_columns' );
function cor_wp_nav_menu_manage_columns() {
  return '';
}
```

Would someone know what I might be overlooking perhaps?

**Edit:**

I'm able to remove the advanced menu properties using `add_filter( 'manage_nav-menus_columns', '__return_false', 200 );`
I'm however still struggling (meaning, I can't remove them) to remove the property fields

Comment: "this should work, but unfortunately, it isn't." ... That isn't very helpful. Could you please explain in detail what you're trying, what output/errors you get and where you're stuck?

Comment: You're right :) In this case I was trying to rename the title key to something like 'test' to see if my filter would work. The outcome however stayed the same `'_title' => __('Show advanced menu properties'),`. If possible, this is what I'm actually trying to accomplish: `add_filter( 'manage_nav-menus_columns', 'cor_wp_nav_menu_manage_columns' ); function cor_wp_nav_menu_manage_columns() { return ''; }`

Comment: :) Please move that in as edit of your Q. You know, not everyone reads the comments.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and mark it as "accepted" so people will know where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some struggling extending `Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit` and using `preg_replace` on the property fields, I've ended with this solution:

```
// removes the `nav-menus.php` 'advanced menu properties' column
add_filter( 'manage_nav-menus_columns', '__return_empty_array', 200 );

add_action( 'admin_footer-nav-menus.php', 'cor_remove_nav_menu_properties' );
/**
 * Removes the `nav-menus.php` 'advanced menu properties' fields.
 */
function cor_remove_nav_menu_properties() {
?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('p').remove('.field-css-classes, .field-description, .field-link-target, .field-xfn, .link-to-original');
});
</script>
<?php
}
```